# Using CMake with prebuilt Cocos2d-x and CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, clion

I am trying to statically link my project to use Cocos2d-x prebuilt libraries but am unable to make my project. I have included the prebuilt library (libcocos2d_2015.lib) which is found, but when trying to build the project it fails when parsing the header files. There are dozens of errors within the header files despite having a static library. As well as this, some of the errors seem to be caused by CMake not defining the `_WIN32` macro which is strange?

I simply want a Cocos2d-x project which is statically linked for WIN32 only. I am not interested in any other platforms right and have been trying to get this building for hours.

Background information is that I am running within Mingw-w64 using GCC and the CLion IDE.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(CocosTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

find_library(COCOS2D_LIBRARY NAMES libcocos2d_2015 PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

include_directories(include C:/cocos2d-x-3.11.1/cocos)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE INCLUDES include C:/Users/Jared/Documents/cocos2d-x-3.11.1/cocos)

add_executable(CocosTest ${SOURCES} ${INCLUDES})

target_link_libraries(CocosTest ${COCOS2D_LIBRARY})
```

**Errors**

> cocos/platform/CCPlatformConfig.h:143:6: error: #error "Cannot
>   recognize the target platform; are you targeting an unsupported
>   platform?"
>        #error  "Cannot recognize the target platform; are you targeting an unsupported platform?"
>
> cocos/base/CCRef.h:48:14: error: variable 'cocos2d::CC_DLL
>   cocos2d::Clonable' has initializer but incomplete type  class CC_DLL
>   Clonable
>
> cocos/base/CCRef.h:149:5: error: 'friend' used outside of class
>        friend class AutoreleasePool;
>        ^
>
> etc.

Comment: No needs to list header files in `add_executable` call. Note, that you problem is unrelated of whether *Cocos2d-x* is built statically or not: its headers remains the same.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I figured but was just trying everything I could think of to get this working! Thanks for pointing that out.